# Touch ID for KeyChain no PIN fallback

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, keychain, touch-id

I am working to integrate touch ID for my App for user login. since I am going to store the username and password to be used in the future by touch, I found that localAuthenticate will not work for me and i have to use the new ACL to access the keychain.

I got all the code to read/write to the keychain with ACL fine. but I see only right now one option "kSecAccessControlUserPresence" for SecAccessControlCreateFlags in SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(...). this is allowing the user per apple documentation to fallback to the PIN code if they do not want to use touch ID. is there anyway to only allow the access to those keys with touch ID, and if it failed then the user has to enter there credentials manually?

I have other alternatives but I am trying to avoid them:

- Option A: Use LocalAuthenticate and I will do the encryption for my credential in userdeafults but i have to figure out where to store the key? any ideas?
- Option B: keep using ACL and key Chain but I have to figure out if there is away if the user used PIN code or touch id. if they used touch id then I will go ahead an use the info i got from key chain to log in, if they used pin and I will ask them again with LocalAuthenticate. if they canceled it then i will not log in, if they verified with touch id then i will use the credential from keychain to login.

UPDATE: Just in case someone asked why i do not want the PIN, Our lawyers did not accept the concept of a 4 digit pin code as way to access they key chain where we store the passwords.

Comment: Your requirements do not make much sense; if someone knows the passcode, they can add a new fingerprint. So, even if you could require a fingerprint and reject a passcode, you gain no additional security. (You could suggest to your users that they set up a longer passcode if you want.)

Comment: Why not just set a passcode policy for a stronger code? If you are using TouchID you don't need to offer a fallback to a PIN, and the app passcode that you use can be different from the device passcode.

Comment: agreed that if someone knows the PIN code they can add there finger print but I do not want argue this to the legal team, they just want finger print or user has to enter his password (to our system) manually. Also Apple designed the local Authenticate process to use only Finger print so why not extend it to the Key chain ACL and give us control on what to pick.

We can not force our users to switch their PIN form simple 4 numbers to long password.

Answer (score 2):

This is now available on iOS 9:

- `kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet` - "Touch ID from the set of currently enrolled fingers. Touch ID must be available and at least one finger must be enrolled. When fingers are added or removed, the item is invalidated."
- `kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny` - "Touch ID (any finger). Touch ID must be available and at least one finger must be enrolled. Item is still accessible by Touch ID even if fingers are added or removed".

Comment: I integrated touch id in my app.I want to use the touch id as a second secure authentication. I want to detect if new fingerprints were added or removed. Could you help me with programmatically usage?

Comment: These two access controls are now marked as deprecated in the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/ksecaccesscontroltouchidany?language=objc).

Comment: These have been renamed in the iOS 11.3 SDK and upwards (the current names will now issue a deprecation warning) - the new names are kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet and kSecAccessControlBiometryAny

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but biometrySet and biometryAny still fallback to device pin.